# makefile/nmake : strip out folder bits from the file list

Tags: c++, makefile, nmake

I have a makefile (using nmake & VC++ 2005):

```
CPP_OBJS = $(CPP_SOURCE:.cpp=.obj)


$(TARGET) : $(CPP_OBJS)
    $(link) $(ldebug) $(lflags) /DLL \
    $(LIBPATHS) \
    $out:$@ $(CPP_OBJS) $(conlibs)
```

The problem is link step fails because $(CPP_OBJS) are expanded into the list of files where each filename is prepended with a folder name (that way it was generated from CPP_SOURCE) . And since all of the .obj files are in the current folder (results of the compilation) - the link.exe fails to locate .objs.

I need something like: (I found it here: http://uw714doc.sco.com/cgi-bin/info2html?%28make.info%29File%2520Name%2520Functions&lang=en)

`$(notdir NAMES...)'
      Extracts all but the directory-part of each file name in NAMES.
      If the file name contains no slash, it is left unchanged.
      Otherwise, everything through the last slash is removed from it.

but that thing does not seem to be working for NMAKE which comes with VC++ 2005.

Any ideas how to overcome this issue are greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you use GNU make? (http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm)

Answer (score 3):

`$(notdir)` is not working for you because that's a GNU make feature, while you are using NMAKE.

It's not entirely clear to me what you're trying to do, but the short answer to your question is to use NMAKE automatic variables with file modifiers.  In this case `$(**)` is the list of all prereqs to the target, and adding the `F` modifier will strip out the directory names.  For example:

```
CPP_SOURCE=subdir/foo.cpp subdir/bar.cpp
CPP_OBJS=$(CPP_SOURCE:.cpp=.obj)
all: $(CPP_OBJS)
        @echo Unmodified: $(**)
        @echo Filenames only: $(**F)
```

Assuming you have a directory `subdir` with files `foo.obj` and `bar.obj`, this prints:

```
Unmodified: subdir/foo.obj subdir/bar.obj
Filenames only: foo.obj bar.obj
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since [nmake](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd9y37ha(VS.80).aspx) doesn't support '$(notdir NAMES...)' and its [macro substitution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsd42ets(VS.80).aspx) doesn't support easy removal of the folder hierarchy from the source file name(s), would it be possible to change the compilation to output the object file(s) into the same folder(s) as the source?

```
cpp.obj:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) /c /Fo $*.obj $*.cpp
```

I'm no nmake expert, but I believe this may help you to overcome this issue.

Comment: Macro subsitution doesn't help, but automatic variables and file modifiers do.

Answer (score -1):

I don't really know NMAKE (I use GNU Make) but I think you have basically two options:

1. Experiment with the text functions until you get what you want. You don't say what $(notdir...) does, but maybe you can get the desired effect with, say, $(patsubst...), or some clever arrangement of $(subst...), $(word...) and $(words...).

   Leave out the paths from the beginning. If CPP_SOURCE doesn't contain paths then neither will CPP_OBJS. Use [VPATH](http://uw714doc.sco.com/cgi-bin/info2html?(make.info)General%2520Search&lang=en) to tell make where to find the sources.